# Cursor Grabbing while using drag_and_drop_by_offset (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I need to drag this scale [image] and when I run this code:

```
HandScale = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-xform="scale"]')
GridLineX = browser.find_element_by_class_name('outlined')
bottomLeft = browser.find_element_by_class_name('bottomLeft')
print GridLineX.size
action_chains = ActionChains(browser)
action_chains.drag_and_drop_by_offset(HandScale, 30, 30).click_and_hold(HandScale).perform()
```

It still has the grabbing effect Shown here:
[image]

Is there anyway to remove this effect before running the other part of my script?

Comment: So your question is how to release or "drop" the page after grabbing it?

Comment: Would action_chains.release() work?

Comment: Thanks man! I’ll try it when I have the chance I’ll let you know.

Comment: It still hasn't worked any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the `release()` function in `action_chains` which is designed to do exactly that. The line to add at the end of your current file would be:

```
action_chains.release().perform()
```

**Edit after feedback that this didn't work:** what if you do the `release()` inside your existing `action_chains`, and simply add a `pause()` after your `click_and_hold(HandScale)` so that the click is actually held and not immediately released.  Finally, since you use a webelement argument in `click_and_hold(HandScale)` I would try to release on that element with `release(HandScale)`. So, your `action_chains` might do what you want if you use the following:

```
 action_chains.drag_and_drop_by_offset(HandScale, 30, 30).click_and_hold(HandScale).pause(5).release(HandScale).perform()
```

If **THAT** doesn't work, the WebDriver API has a method called `reset_actions()` that, according to the documentation "Clears actions that are already stored locally and on the remote end".  I would add this under your current `action_chains`, but you could try inserting it before `perform()` in your current code. The line to add would just look like this:

```
action_chains.reset_actions().perform()
```

If none of this works for you, you could try

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('cursor')", element")
```

If you need I think can help you figure out what to execute if none of the above works.

Comment: Alright I’ll try in when I have the chance thanks very much.

Comment: When you say it hasn't worked, you mean that element still has `cursor: grabbing` on that div?

Comment: @AliAl-Jabur Take a look at the edits I've made to my answer and see if you can get the mouse to release.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Alright thanks a lot man I’ll give it a look when I have some time means a lot.

Comment: Hey man umm none of them worked can you try to help me with the excute_script.

Comment: yea is there any way I can make it stop grabbing

Comment: I’ll see if I can figure out some Javascript shortly.  I hate the damn action_chains, they never work right!

Comment: Try using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('cursor'), element")`--I edit this into my answer--after your `action_chains`.  If that doesn't work I will be puzzled.

Comment: ill give it a try but can you explain what element is?{nvm}

Comment: `element` would be the div which has the `cursor = 'grabbing'` attribute.  I'll edit something I *think* will find that into the question.  Also noticed you are using `browser`, not `driver` so I'll change that.

Comment: @AliAl-Jabur **WAIT**.... the `cursor: grabbing` isn't an attribute itself, it's part of that div's `style` attribute, which you have highlighted. Problem is I can't see the whole thing--the part after `display:` is offscreen.  Can you please edit into your question the full text of that div, and the `input` attribute in particular?